# Windows 7 add ftp location to Favorites in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, ftp, favorites

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, and am trying to add a local FTP location to my Windows explorer favorites. For some reason, when I've browsed to say `ftp://localaddr`, and right click on `favorites` and click `add current location`, nothing happens! Is the bookmarking of ftp locations just not supported?

Maybe related: It is a location which requires username/password login (Windows has already saved the password)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up Explorer and go to `C:\Users\<username>\Links` then create a new shortcut into this folder. (File -> New -> Shortcut)

Put the address `ftp://localaddr` into the location field, then hit Next and Finish. You should now have it in your favorites.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it when I get home. Do you happen to know if its a genuine bug or this is "works as designed"? Seems to me like either a bad bug or terribly designed UI, disappointing coming from Windows 7...

Answer (score 0):

Adding an ftp link to the list of favorites works, even when the link requires a user/passwd combi. But only when refering to a directory inside the ftp link, not to the top level directory itself.

Answer (score -1):

I found a simpler method at Microsoft's [Work with files on an FTP site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-vista/work-with-files-on-an-ftp-site) page:

1. Open Windows Explorer and navigate to "Computer".
2. Right-click anywhere in the folder,
   and then click "Add a network location". 
   This displays the "Add Network Connection" wizard.
3. Click "Next".
4. In the wizard, select "Choose a custom network location",
   and then click "Next".
5. Enter the name of the FTP site, with the full `ftp://` in front of it,
   and then click "Next".
6. To use a name and password, clear the "Log on anonymously" check box,
   type a user name, and then click "Next".
7. By default, the name of the shortcut is the same as the FTP address. 
   If you want to give the shortcut a different name,
   type it in the "Type a name for this network location" box.  Click "Next".
8. If you do not want the FTP site to open
   after you're done setting up the shortcut,
   clear the "Open this network location when I click Finish" check box. 
   Click "Finish". 
   A shortcut to the FTP site appears in the Computer folder. 
   You can drag that shortcut to your desktop so that it's easy to find later.

One issue I have with this method is that whatever file I open in it
opens in my internet browser instead of opening in Windows itself. 
I hope there is a way to change it.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.